# A simple electro-mechanical model of a DC brushed gearmotor

Tags: dc-motor, simulation, electro-mechanical

I'm trying to arrive at an estimate of motor angular velocity during startup phase, specifically the time it takes for the output shaft to rotate n degrees from power on. I'm looking at DC brushed worm gearmotor, e.g. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000984935797.html, with inertial load attached to the output shaft. The load inertia and motor torque/RPM curve is known, and the power source internal resistance is negligible. Is there a simulation tool I can use to get an answer or get a graph/function of startup speed?

Comment: There is probably a simulation tool available, but questions about product recommendations are "off topic" here. My approach would be to use what I have and am familiar with, MS Excel.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Where do you see `questions about product recommendations` in my post? I'm asking for a motor model, not motor recommendation.

Comment: By "simulation tool" did you not mean a software product?

Comment: @CharlesCowie OK, I see what you meant. I'm fine with an equation, if talking about a software tool is verboten here.

Comment: Someone may provide a simulation suggestion, but they might not because of the reason I mentioned. There are no votes to close or flags, so no one else has seen a problem with the question. I could offer a little more help, but I  am too tired.